# JS - My loop and if statements print out the wrong string?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

My loop seems to print out the wrong string. I need 15 to print out fizzbuzz. To me it seems that it should.

```
 var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

 for (i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
     if (numbers[i]%3 === 0 && numbers % 5 !== 0 ){
         console.log("Fizz");
     } else if (numbers[i] % 5 === 0 && numbers[i] % 3 !== 0) {
         console.log("Buzz");
     } else if (numbers[i] % 3 === 0 && numbers[i]%5 === 0) {
         console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
     } else {
         console.log(numbers[i]);
     } 
};
```

Comment: At line 4 you forgot a `[i]` after `numbers`.

Comment: @OlivierGrech Nice catch.

Comment: can use numbers.forEach(function(number){ // your logic }); to simplify code.You dont have to deal with indices then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you wrote `numbers % 5` instead of `numbers[i] % 5` at line 4.

As a general rule, it's important to store your iterator in a variable, to avoid this (and cache the value instead of retrieving it every time). Use `for..of` ES6 syntax if you can, it makes things easier to write, more readable and less error prone.

```
for (const number of numbers) {
   if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 !== 0 ){
     console.log("Fizz");
   } else if (number % 5 === 0 && number % 3 !== 0) {
     console.log("Buzz");
   } else if (number % 3 === 0 && number%5 === 0) {
     console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
   } else {
     console.log(numbers[i]);
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that Fizzbuzz test is a simple interview question imagined by the guy who made StackOverflow. Failing at this test is not an option :) So train your code style to write less error-prone code.

Try to store the values you will consider in a variable before testing it in multiple if/else statements for instance, it's a good habit, and it makes code more readable, and easier to debug. See here, by not doing that, you spent a lot of time to understand the error, and had to ask on SO about this. Think about the cost it would have if it was a real code in industry.

Good luck, code safe :)